# strerror_r has no effect

Tags: c, gcc

Here is a simple program which illustrates the problem.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    char buf [30];
    strerror_r (0, buf, sizeof (buf));

    std :: cout << "strerror_r(0): " << buf << std :: endl;
    std :: cout << "strerror(0): " << strerror (0) << std :: endl;
}
```

Here is the output.

```
strerror_r(0): 
strerror(0): Success
```

Why is there nothing in `buf`?

(Compiled on Ubuntu with gcc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [man strerror_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r):

> The XSI-compliant version of strerror_r() is provided if:
>   (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE
>   **Otherwise, the GNU-specific version is provided.**

and further down:

> **The GNU-specific strerror_r()** returns a pointer to a string containing the error message. This may be either a pointer to a string that the function stores in buf, or a pointer to some (immutable) static string (in which case buf is unused). If the function stores a string in buf, then at most buflen bytes are stored (the string may be truncated if buflen is too small and errnum is unknown). The string always includes a terminating null byte.

The program must be using the GNU-specific version and not populating `buf`. I reproduced the behaviour of the posted program but stored the return value of `strerror_r()` and it was not the same address as `buf`.

Comment: I can only confirm this. `strerror_r` is defined as `char* strerror_r(int, char*, size_t)` in ubuntu with gcc 4.6.3. `std::cout << strerror_r(0, buf, sizeof(buf));` outputs "Success" as expected.

Comment: Well that' dumb. Why the hell doesn't the GNU version have a different name if it has different semantics? Ridiculous. But thanks.

Comment: @spraff: I guess that GNU `strerror_r` predated the Posix one.

Comment: As a solution, use the `strerror_l` function. It's standard, thread-safe, behaves the same on all systems on which it's supported, and has a much nicer interface than `strerror_r`.

Comment: @R.., thanks. Are you certain that is standard? I couldn't locate it in the C99 standard draft that I have or at cppreference.com.